# Dockerfile best practice regarding Nexus artifacts and build instructions

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, nexus

I am sort of new to Docker and I am trying to understand some best practice recommendations regarding the build process in the  Dockerfile.

I know that for a traditional JAVA application, we will typically use maven to pull dependent libraries from Nexus repository, source code from GIT or other CM and then build the application. Finally,  the output .war file will again be stored  in a tagged release folder in Nexus repository to be copied over to different environments (dev/qa/production etc.).  But one challenge that remained was inconsistencies between the  different environments and we are trying to use containers to solve that problem - meaning once it is tested in a container, we can just push that container up the pipeline to different environment and they should work without any issue since the container includes the environmental dependencies plus everything the web application needs as a package.

But my question is regarding the Dockerfile. So is the Dockerfile supposed to replace the function  of Maven ? Should it include the complete build instructions for the application  ? I know we still pull the source code from GIT and dependent libraries from Nexus by referencing  them in the Dockerfile but where does the  output .war file go ? Is there still a need to store that in Nexus ? Since  we can version the Docker containers through some of the tools such as OpenShift and roll back as necessary, what will be the purpose of storing the output .war file in Nexus.

One scenario I can think of is related to patching. When an OS/security patch is available, we update the base Docker image and rebuild the Application specific Docker image to apply the patch. But what happens to the application in this case ? Do we need to rebuild the application every time we need to apply a patch ? If application build instructions are embedded into the Dockerfile, and we have to rebuild the application container image, doesn't the  application also get rebuilt automatically ? Or can Dockerfile only execute certain instructions - skip build application part if no code change or when you tell it to skip etc.) . Should Dockerfile reference to a Nexus repository for the application .war file so in the case the .war file doesn't change, it doesn't rebuild ?

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it'd be a good idea to version control the application build artifacts (war, jar etc.) separately in Nexus and not doing the application build process as part of the docker build. We have a similar pipeline and the way we do it is this:

- Checkout source code from SCM
- Build with Maven and upload the build artifact to Nexus for version control
- Inject the built artifact in the base Docker image(i.e. openjdk) as part of the docker build step
- Push the image to the registry
- CD kicks in and deploys the latest image

> *Should Dockerfile reference to a Nexus repository for the application .war file so in the case the .war file doesn't change, it doesn't
>   rebuild?*

Yes, that's correct, you can use curl command in your Dockerfile to download the artifacts from Nexus, no need to rebuild application everytime you make change to your Dockerfile.